# java.io.StreamTokenizer produces null token when encounter an underscore

Tags: java, stream, null, tokenize, java-io

I have a StreamTokenizer for parsing tokens. When I pass the following to the stdin:

```
a b_c d
```

The parsed tokens (on stdout) are:

```
a
b
null
c
d
```

Why is that so? If the underscore is a word character, there should be 3 tokens with the second one "b_c". If the underscore is a delimiter, there should be 4 tokens. I see no point in a null token.

Q1: Why is there the null token?

Q2: Why would someone design a StreamTokenizer in the way to produce null tokens?

Ideone script: http://ideone.com/e.js/RFbPpJ

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(br);
        while (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            System.out.println(st.sval);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc :

> If the current token is a word token, this field contains a string
>   giving the characters of the word token. When the current token is a
>   quoted string token, this field contains the body of the string. The
>   current token is a word when the value of the ttype field is TT_WORD.
>   The current token is a quoted string token when the value of the ttype
>   field is a quote character.
>
> The initial value of this field is null.

Which mean that none of the condition were met and `null` was outputed.

In other word, the underscore's ttype is neither considered as a word or a quoted string.

The documentation for `ttype` specify

> After a call to the nextToken method, this field contains the type of
>   the token just read. For a single character token, its value is the
>   single character, converted to an integer. For a quoted string token,
>   its value is the quote character. Otherwise, its value is one of the
>   following: TT_WORD indicates that the token is a word. TT_NUMBER
>   indicates that the token is a number. TT_EOL indicates that the end of
>   line has been read. The field can only have this value if the
>   eolIsSignificant method has been called with the argument true. TT_EOF
>   indicates that the end of the input stream has been reached.
>
> The initial value of this field is -4.

Note that the -4 value is equals to TT_NOTHING.

To recognize the underscore as a word, you can use `tokenizer.wordChars('_', '_');`

> wordChars is used to specify that all characters c in the range low <=
>   c <= high are word constituents. A word token consists of a word
>   constituent followed by zero or more word constituents or number
>   constituents.

If you want the underscore to be an ordinary char instead of a word char then there is also a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#ordinaryChar(int)) for that.

Note that giving in '_' as both delimiter to wordChars will allow only the underscore to be a word character, so you might want to set the bounds that fit your needs.

**Edit :** To answer your comment, in short, an underscore is treated as part of an identifier which is why it is not mapped to anything hence return null.

If you look at the not-documented private constructor of the StreamTokenizer class, you will have a better idea of how each char is handled :

```
private StreamTokenizer() {
    wordChars('a', 'z');
    wordChars('A', 'Z');
    wordChars(128 + 32, 255);
    whitespaceChars(0, ' ');
    commentChar('/');
    quoteChar('"');
    quoteChar('\'');
    parseNumbers();
}
```

The underscore is ASCII code 95 which is not in the bounds.

Comment: Maybe my concept of tokening is a bit skewed, but I think the Tokenizer should for every character be able to decide whether it is a part of a token or it is a delimiter... (still missing answer for Q2)

Comment: Almost... I would like to know why whould someone designed it so there are characters not considered to be in a token / delimiter. Is there some purpose? (other than to cause NullPointerException to let me know there is yet another unknown character)

Comment: @mirelon as I said, the underscore is designed to be a part of an identifier. Therefore, when met, if the identifier is not identified, nothing is mappend and null is returned. This may return NPE, however NPE are easier to test than unexpected behaviour (for example if you would have mis-typed an identifier).

Comment: Ok, so I am obviosly missing the concept of "identifier" in the context of stream of characters... could you please explain?

Comment: @mirelon identifier here is just a random term that I used. What you have to understand is that by default the underscored is not in any bounds (refer to constructor I posted). So, if you don't re-define the default values it will work that way, considering that underscore should not be accepted. In my opinion, the reason why it is done like that is not to throw null and NPE, but to make it more evident if an un-expected value is read. But this is not really important, as a Tokenizer, like any other programs that you want to fully use, should be set custom values that fit your needs.

Comment: So, tu sum it up, it is intentional to allow tokenizing only standard characters and let developer know (the hard way) whenever a non-standard character occurs in the stream. I really don't like this approach...

Comment: @mirelon Maybe you would prefer a StringTokenizer ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for suggestion, StringTokenizer seems to provide sensible defaults. However, can it be used in a streaming mode? (The input data do not fit in the memory)

Comment: Not directly, but you could read the string and pass it to the tokenizer.